# How can I use Google Calendar etc. with iCloud?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, icloud, google-calendar

Since 3 years, I'm a Linux user. Now I am thinking about switching to OSX. I informed myself about OSX and looked into many youtube videos about it, but still I have a few questions about it

At the moment I'm using Google Calendar as my primary calendar. In my google account I have a dashboard where I see an overview over my data, calendars etc. Where can I find this in my apple Account? If I use iCloud, how does this work? Are calendars etc.. only synced over icloud and Apple devices?

If I don't want to use iCloud, is it possible to integrate my google Account into the OSX calendar etc?

Comment: You had several questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your additional question, but feel free to ask them separately

Comment: @patrix okay, thanks. It just seemed a bit silly to create more then 1 thread for such simple questions.

Comment: It makes the site hard to use if you have multiple questions (which answer are you going to accept if several answers cover only part of your questions?). But for your other questions, a trip to the next shop selling Apple computers might prove helpful as well.

Comment: Or you could join the chat room and discuss your questions there (might be easier to get help if you can interact with others)

Answer (score 2):

Your Google account can be added to System Preferences → Internet Accounts. There you can select the services that you would like to enable.

[image]

For example, selecting the Calendars service will enable all of your calendars in your Google account in the Calendars app on OS X.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. That would make iCoud pretty redundant, or not? Does iCloud have other advantages or is it just the possibility to sync data between apple devices?

Comment: @user3025786 It's mostly personal preference on OS X. I'm not aware of any categorical syncing benefits of iCloud or Google, unless you factor in iOS devices, where the benefits of iCloud are obvious.

Comment: Google Calendar and iCal don't communicate seamlessly. Alerts can get removed if they don't exist on GCal ("popup with message" for example gets killed by GCal, whereas "alert" will still work). There are occasional issues syncing, where GCal will refuse to allow a change, especially with recurring events. But overall they are 95% compatible. I have had several GCal accounts syncing with iCal on all Apple devices (MacBook, iPhone, iPad) for years now.